# Windows Phone 8 Browser and Basic Auth

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-8

How can I use the built in browser (IE) for pages that require basic authentication?
In windows phone 8, I never see a result or popup that asks for the credentials.
In Windows Phone 8.1 (Emulator), I see a page "Autorization required. This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. [..]"

I also tried to provide user and passwort via url [http://myuser:mypassword@myserver.com](http://myuser%3amypassword@myserver.com) but this did not help.

Is it impossible to open basic authenticated page on Windows Phone?!

EDIT: to make it clear: I want to open such a page in the browser and not within a webview of a new application. So any C# examples won't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/dn632140). There is a sample project with various examples, from authentication, authorization to skydrive interaction and more.

Comment: I want to use the build in browser and not write an app for this.